# On a ssh session how can I set env variables and run shell commands?

Tags: python, shell, ssh, environment-variables

I need to :

1. ssh to a remote server (currently I have used paramiko.SSHClient)
2. For the session set env variables that's required to run a set of subsequent commands/scripts
3. Run the commands/scripts.

My env settings are temporary for that session alone, so I guess modifying `~/.ssh/environment` is not an option. <<< Please correct if I am wrong.

Also the server is password protected, so I guess subprocess.Popen(ssh) is also out of the question? Again, I am still trying things, please correct me.

I have tried with no success:

```
a. ssh.exec_command(env_export_commands)
b. ssh.exec_command(command=dummy,environment=env_export_commands_dictionary).
```

But after either of the above, I still see the old values in 'env'.
Any pointers to what I am missing is highly appreciated.

Comment: Learnt that each exec_command is executed in a different shell,so setting and checking env ( or any other command that uses the newly set env variables) need to get executed in single exec_command

command_set = "export env1=value1; env;" + script_using_env
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command_set)

Answer (score 0):

Learnt that each exec_command is executed in a different shell,so setting and checking env ( or any other command that uses the newly set env variables) need to get executed in single exec_command

i.e :

```
 command_set = "export env1=value1; env;" + script_using_env 

 stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command_set)
```